# How to write a text if conditions met in Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I want to automatically create a text depending on what the other columns shows.
For example, if in `A1` there is "Service", then `G1`='1'.
And if in `B1` there is "True", then `G1` = "11" (as in '1' + '1').

I hope this is understandable...

Comment: Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome. Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Have you tried the given solutions? Did any work for you? If not we should try finding out why. If yes, as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, you should [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this in `G1`:

```
=if(regexmatch(A1,"Service"),1,)&if(regexmatch(A1,"True"),1,)
```

It checks for `Service` with regexmatch as a condition
If true > 1
If false > nothing
Same idea with `True`then it concatenates the two values with `&`

Comment: Welcome. Please remember that as per [site guidelines](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) when an answer addresses your question, [accept](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it and even [upvote](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/why-vote) it so others can benefit as well.

Answer (score 0):

You mention:

> ...automatically create a text...
>   ...if in `A1` there is "Service", then `G1`='1'. And if in `B1` there is "True", then `G1` = "11" (as in '1' + '1')

You do **not** clarify what the result should be when `A1` is **not** "Service".

So assuming that "*if `A1` is **not** Service*" you only want `A1` returned, you could use

```
=IF(AND(U11=true,T11="Service"),IF(T11="Service","1",T11)&"-asd",IF(T11="Service","1",T11))
```

Of course you can change `-asd` to whatever you like. Your result would be `1-asd` or `1ABX` or even `11`, `1342` etc.
*(You have to remember though that a result like `11` or `1324` will look like a number but will actually be text)*

Functions used:

- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`AND`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093301)